# Any conclusive statement on the controversial book The Bell Curve

Tags: social-psychology, intelligence, iq

[*The Bell Curve: Intelligence and Class Structure in American Life*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bell_Curve), an empirical study arguing for IQ correlations with success, genes and race apparently sparked a big controversy in the US since 1992 when it was first published.

The central thesis of writers Richard J. Hernstein and Charles Murray is that intelligence is partly a genetically inherited property and that there are meaingful differences in average IQ between East Asians, White Americans, and African Americans due to their different ethnicities.

I read there have been a lot of critical literature in response to this. But has there been any conclusive statement on this question 26 years after the publication of this work? As a non-specialist I find reading through the massive literature around the work to be daunting.

Comment: Related: [Does a non-knowledge based, or knowledge corrected IQ test exist, and what are its results per race?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20652/7001)